# Stop XTerm from moving text upwards on window resize, when cursor is at last row?

Tags: terminal, xterm, ansi-escape, terminal-emulator

In the Alternate Screen Buffer mode in XTerm-like terminal emulators, when the cursor is on the last row and the terminal window is resized so that it has less rows, all text in the terminal is shifted upwards.

Can anyone point me to what is going on here? I can't find any related escape sequences to turn this behavior off, or any way to intercept SIGWINCH to move the cursor before the shift happens. It seems like it may be related to scrolling to keep the cursor on the screen.

**I'd really like the screen display to not change, even if the cursor is no longer on screen after a resize.**

I'm not using ncurses or other libraries, just escape sequences and system calls.

Comment: It's in the manual page: [resizeGravity](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:resizeGravity)

Comment: @ThomasDickey I'm guessing there is no way to do this through an escape sequence or system call then?  I'm not sure I understand how X Toolkit resources are set. Thanks.

Comment: yes - some internal-state which corresponds to X resources can be set through control sequences, but this isn't one of those.